# как переверсти laravel проект с bcrypt на md5 шифрование?

Tags: laravel, хеширование, md5

Есть laravel проект, и там по стандарту, все шифруется в bcrypt. Мне необходимо перевести его в md5? Как это правильно сделать? Что бы потом не было проблем с регистрацией и авторизацией.

Comment: А зачем вы хотите ослабить безопасность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете добавить default null поле для нового хеша пароля.
На момент успешной авторизации вы знаете действительный пароль пользователя, значит если новый пароль в базе null, а старый хэш совпал, то сохраняете новый хеш в новое поле, а поле со старым паролем скидываете в null.
Через пару месяцев/полгода/год/выбрать_по_настроению вырезаете код старого хэша и дропаете колонку из базы. Всем желающим авторизоваться, но у кого стоит null вместо пароля - пишете, что необходимо пройти процедуру восстановления пароля.

Активная аудитория изменение не заметит. Теми, кто заходит слишком редко - придётся пожертвовать и заставить пройти более длинную процедуру.

Или Перегенерить всё на рандомные пароли, и в БД поставить флаг "change_password".

При заходе просто показывать ошибку что нужно воспользоваться функцией "Восстановить пароль"

Comment: Спасибо большое.